# Checkout event receiver

Tags: event-receivers

I am using the below code to checkout the document in a library when an item was updated.  The library has versioning and content approval enabled.  My problem is that when you check in the document to publish a new version the receiver checks out the document.  Is there a way to code that if the item is awaiting approval then to not check it out?

```
/// <summary>
/// List Item Events
/// </summary>
public class EventReceiver1 : SPItemEventReceiver
{
   /// <summary>
   /// An item was added.
   /// </summary>
   public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
       base.ItemUpdated(properties);
       SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
       item.File.CheckOut();
       item.SystemUpdate(false);
   }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can check what is the status of the document in the library.

Check this code:

```
SPListItem listItem = GetListItem();
var moderationInformation = listItem.ModerationInformation;
if (moderationInformation != null)
{
    if (moderationInformation.Status == SPModerationStatusType.Approved)
    {         
        //approved     
    }
    else if (moderationInformation.Status == SPModerationStatusType.Denied)
    {         
        //rejected     
    }
    else if (moderationInformation.Status == SPModerationStatusType.Draft)
    {         
        //item is in edit mode and yet send to pending state.     
    }
    else if (moderationInformation.Status == SPModerationStatusType.Scheduled)
    {         
        //approval is waiting to be processed by a timer service.     
    }
}
```

[Help Link](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.in/2011/02/sharepoint-2010-approvereject-content.html)

Let me know if you have any query.

Thanks

Comment: I think the above is useful but I am unsure on how to add this to my original code (still a beginner).

Answer (score 1):

You can put a check like this :

```
       SPFile file=item.File;
       if(file.Level==SPFileLevel.Published)
        {
          if (file.CheckOutType == SPFile.SPCheckOutType.None)
           {
            file.CheckOut();  // Checking out the file
           }
        }
```

Comment: This seems to put it in a loop as I cannot check in the item also I added systemupdate(false) to your code and the version number still increase.  Any ideas?? :-)

Comment: Get list var list = properties.List; then use list.Update(); after System.Update(false);