# SharePoint Document Library Allow one view per item at a time

Tags: document-library

This is a hard thing to Google as I keep getting results for co-authoring. My question is I need a document library that forces a document to be checked out when you try to view it, and restricts anyone else from viewing this document. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Lists have a setting to require checkout under `Versioning Settings`, but it is based on making actual changes, not simply opening the document.

You can potentially use this in conjunction with a "[force-edit](http://blog.sharedove.com/adisjugo/index.php/2012/09/29/open-sharepoint-files-in-edit-mode-from-client-applications-and-not-read-only/)", to make sure that documents always open in edit mode.

For advanced scenarios (e.g. lock down the doc, etc.), you may need to write an event receiver,

[Checkout event receiver](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110206/checkout-event-receiver)

[image]

Comment: It's definitely a crazy requirement they came to me with. I'll look into the event receiver. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of users that need to access the document, and in what order they need to access the doc, you could use a workflow to change permissions of the doc, and assign a task to the users to review the doc. Once they've completed the task, the workflow could revoke their permissions, assign read-only permissions to the next user, and even send the next user an email with a link to the doc. This is pretty easy to set up via a 2010-based SharePoint designer workflow. It's possible with a 2013-based workflow, though quite challenging.  (if you're not familiar, the versions here are a reference to versions of the workflow engine, not SharePoint.)

Or, you could have different libraries with different permissions. For example, library1 could give the finance dept read access. Library2 could give the engineering group read access. Etc. Then, a workflow could move the doc from one library to the next. This would allow multiple users, but only one group at a time, which might meet your needs? This is also much easier to configure, and would be simple to set up with either SharePoint Designer workflows or with Flow.